# How to check number of active connections in mysql database using java and close it

Tags: java, mysql

I want to check the number of active open connections in mysql database using java and close it.

I tried using query only

```
  SHOW STATUS LIKE 'threads_connected';
```

With this can anyone tell me how to find and close the connection. I know when a database connection is established we need to close it immediately but for some other requirement i want to know active connections list and delete that list.

Any idea please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I pulled aout the strings used bei HeidiSQL
First for getting a list with active connections(Processes):
    SELECT `ID`, `USER`, `HOST`, `DB`, `COMMAND`, `TIME`, `STATE`, LEFT(`INFO`, 51200) AS `Info` FROM `information_schema`.`PROCESSLIST`

The for deleting a processes:

```
KILL {The ID of the Process};
```

It would probably be enough to `SELECT` only the ID of the Process but with that query you get all Information needed.

Comment: Did you replaced `{The ID of the Process}` with the ID you got from the select-query before?